# Cheapest and easier way to turn lawn landscape to desert landscape

Tags: lawn, desert

I'd like to convert my front yard from lawn landscape to desert landscape to consume less water and less maintenance, and I'd like it to be done in cheapest way possible without using any pesticide. What would be the easiest approach to do that?

Something looks likes
[image]

to

[image]

Comment: A search term that can help you is [Xeriscaping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xeriscaping) (X pronounced as a Z)

Comment: Are you in a desertine environment naturally, like Phoenix, Riverside or San Jose? I.e. Before your city was there, was it rocks and chapperal, or was it forest?

Comment: Seems to me you could just throw down some tarps for a bit to kill that grass and lay out some gravel over top of it but perhaps you have something else in mind?

Comment: yes. I am located in a desertine environment.

Comment: Is that grass or fake grass?

Comment: real grass @WayfaringStranger